# Android answer database

Tags: database

I am pretty new in this game so please do not judge me harshly.

So I need to build a question/answer database for an app.

The idea is simple:
User types a question and if I have an answer in my database, it gives an answer. If I do not have an answer, it goes for my manual moderation, so I can add new answers for the future.

I do not know if someone has already build a software like this and I can just buy one, or do I have to hire someone to build one from the ground. Which language should I use? Which software?

I know that Java, C++ and SQL are most popular languages for that type of jobs, but are they the best solution or there are better languages?
I need a database that can hold a **really huge amount of data**.

I would really appreciate any help guys!

and if any of you can build me this database, I do not mind to hire a freelancer.

Thank you!

Best Regards,
Ayazhan.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do it. 
if you have some knowledge in SQl then you  can make an local Db in your app and consume it according to requirement. The simple question and answer app contains set of predefined questions.

The above link will help you to develop this app.